# Shopify Custom "Buy Sample" Button that Adds to a Cart

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

we are looking for an "Add Sample" type of feature, which adds a 1x item to the cart with the same variant name on a Shopify store.

[image: Here is the Add Sample Button, which adds 1 sample for a set price to the cart]

[image: In the cart, the sample reflects the color name]

You can see a sample of this here, called "Add Sample": https://fabricwholesaledirect.com/products/charmeuse-satin-fabric

Is there a Shopify App the can do this or do we have to custom code this?

I have checked several Shopify Apps but there doesn't appear to be any for this - is this a customization that needs to be hardcoded?

Comment: if you check it closely, then found this is custom build and change the sample ID based on selected variant.

Comment: This is like creating a separate product with fewer price sample variants and then adding to the cart when someone chooses a sample.

Comment: Yes it's what I thought as well. It looks like a custom "Add to Cart" button for a "Dynamic Product" that takes the currently selected color as a custom value.